# Discord Application Bot Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.6, discord, discord.py

currently I am working on a discord bot for a server and need to implement a staff application command such as `!staff-application`. I am trying to make a it in dms so the bot dms the question and the user answers it. and so on till the end where it will save the application in a channel on the server. How would I do this?

Comment: What have you tried this far?

Comment: i have tried to use `on_message()` and `message.author.send("")`

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [Client.wait_for()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.wait_for) function to wait for messages.

Here's an example of a command that loops a list of questions (please note that a brief sleep is hacked in there and that it is probably worth looking into using a proper async loop).

```py
q_list = [
    'What is your favorite color?',
    'Is the Sky Blue?',
    'Am I the best bot ever?'
]

a_list = []


@client.command(aliases=['staff-application'])
async def staff_application(ctx):
    a_list = []
    submit_channel = client.get_channel(<your channel id>)
    channel = await ctx.author.create_dm()

    def check(m):
        return m.content is not None and m.channel == channel

    for question in q_list:
        sleep(.5)
        await channel.send(question)
        msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)
        a_list.append(msg.content)

    submit_wait = True
    while submit_wait:
        await channel.send('End of questions - "submit" to finish')
        msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)
        if "submit" in msg.content.lower():
            submit_wait = False
            answers = "\n".join(f'{a}. {b}' for a, b in enumerate(a_list, 1))
            submit_msg = f'Application from {msg.author} \nThe answers are:\n{answers}'
            await submit_channel.send(submit_msg)
```

Results:

[image: Dialog in DM]

[image: Submitted Answers in Channel]

Using [discord py v1.3.3 from pypi](https://pypi.org/project/discord.py/)

Comment: thank you! only one problem: sleep is not defiened? time.sleep?

Comment: @WilliamJackson - Just add the import, `from time import sleep`

Comment: it saves its own messages to a_list

Comment: @WilliamJackson - it saves the responses/answers to a list called `a_list`.

Comment: it saves the bots questions as answers how do i make it so it only saves the one applying for staff

Comment: @WilliamJackson - notice my final image - it is only showing the answers from the one applying for staff (those are the values saved in `a_list`) - try some print statements, you must have a typo somewhere.

Comment: fixed it changed some code `return m.content is not None and m.channel == channel and m.content != question` so that in the check it checks if the bot sent it

Comment: @WilliamJackson - interesting - My bot messages ignored in `on_message()`. You must not have an `on_message` event.

Comment: messages with your command prefix are not exclude by the check, which could cause some wiered behavior. Also it would be possible for me to answer your questions (okay its not because you do this in dms, but yeah).
Your updated check should something like this:

```return m.content is not None and m.content != question and m.channel == channel and m.author = ctx.author and not m.content.startswith(prefix)
```

Comment: @DaveStSomeWhere Can we use embeds for questions?